# What is localhost.webcache in tcpdump

Tags: networking, logging, rsyslog, localhost, tcpdump

I'm trying to verify that a user is actually logging into my machine and I figured out that looking at `tcpdump` would be reasonable. I'm using the new `omhttp` module for `Rsyslog` to send logs via http from localhost to localhost (dest is `localhost:8080/events`).

tcpdump is called with the following command:
`sudo tcpdump -i lo port 8080`
then I generated some logs by echoing to logger and I get an output like this:

`21:56:25.807778 IP localhost.40250 > localhost.webcache: Flags [P.], seq 2809:2965, ack 327, win 350, options [nop,nop,TS val 3037939874 ecr 3037939649], length 156
21:56:25.807789 IP localhost.webcache > localhost.40250: Flags [.], ack 2965, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 3037939874 ecr 3037939874], length 0`

It seems like I'm generating traffic, but what is the `localhost.webcache`? I've never seen anything like this before and my cursory searches around the network don't bring any enlightenment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`webcache` is the name of the port number, as listed in `/etc/services`, in this case 8080. Use `-n` if you want to see actual numbers.